# Database not updating in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am using axios to post to my api middleware including parameters. But when I try to update the database by submitting the form I get the status `200` using the network tool in chrome but my database does not update.

Here is the Controller Code:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    Mock::find($request['id']);
    $subject = $request['subject'];

    return Mock::where($subject, $subject)->update([
        $subject => $request['list'],
    ]);
}
```

Here is the vue method:

```js
updateDatabase()
{
    // this goes to the api.php middleware in the routes directory 
    let myJSON = JSON.stringify(questionsList);
    axios.post('api/mock',
    {
        id: 1,
        subject: 'english',
        list: myJSON
    })
},
```

Comment: Can you show `mocks` table

Answer (score 1):

Check your `update` method:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // ...
    return Mock::where($subject, $subject)->update([ // <---------
        $subject => $request['list'], // <-------
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

In `where` clauses, the first parameter is the column name, not a value. The same applies when updating attributes. Check this line:

```php
Mock::where($subject, $subject)->/** */
```

Do this instead:

```php
Mock::where('subject', $subject)->/** */
```

By the way, I haven't use your way to get request data, but in case it's returning `null` values, try this approach:

```php
$subject = $request->get('subject');
```

Finally, when doing an `update` operation, the result is a `boolean`, not the updated record. So, in case you expect to return the updated object, do this instead:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Mock::find($id);
    $mock = Mock::where('subject', $subject)->first();
    $mock->update(['subject' => $request->get('list')]);

    return $mock->fresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All problem is `update` function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $mock = Mock::find($request->id);
    return $mock->update([
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'list' => $request->list
    ]);
}
```

Or maybe

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return Mock::where('subject', $request->subject)->update([
        'list' => $request->list,
    ]);
}
```